# Appium drivier initialization returning TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, android, appium, selenoid

I'm trying to connect to an android session using Selenoid to run some tests. This is my code:

```
from appium import webdriver


class MyTestCase():

    def poc_appium_android_selenoid(self):
    
        desired_caps = {
            "platformName":"Android",
            "platformVersion":"7.0",
            "automationName":"UiAutomator1",
            "deviceName":"android",
            "appPackage":"com.android.calculator2",
            "appActivity":"com.android.calculator2.Calculator",
            "enableVNC":True,
            "enableVideo":True
        }
        driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://127.0.0.1:4444/wb/hub", 
desired_capabilities=desired_caps)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mtc = MyTestCase()
    mtc.poc_appium_android_selenoid()
```

Driver initilization is returnig a TypeError: "string indices must be integers", if I don't use any capabilities at all this error persists. It seems that in the remote/webdriver.py file inside the **init** of the WebDriver class, the self.start_session method is executed on line 157. In it, theres a use of the execute method, to which selenoid is returning:

```
{'status': 0, 'value': 'You are using Selenoid 1.10.3!'}
```

it then executes this line and fails because there is no sessionId key in the response obj:

```
self.session_id = response['sessionId']
```

This seems to be an issue with selenoid configuration, any ideas that might help?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in Selenium URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4444/wb/hub => http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
```